# Java AWS SDK S3 upload performance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using `TransferManager` to upload some files to S3.

```
    TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(creds);
    t.upload = tm.upload(bucket, k.key, new File(k.path));
```

The only issue is that I can only get about 1MB/s of upload. If I run 10 different file uploads concurrently, each gets about 100KB/s. Using the AWS console to drag and drop a file, I get about what is expected of my connection speed: 8MB/s.

To further complicate things, I'm on `us-east-1`, but if I test it on `us-west-2`, I get better speeds (I'm in Oregon), but still not what I get via the AWS console.

I'm using the same Windows 7 laptop for both the Java upload and AWS console (using the latest Chrome).

Comment: Use [TransferManagerConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManagerConfiguration.html) and experiment with the `setMultipartUploadThreshold` to see if the performance improves.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the max threads (I didn't get much better performance past 64; [it seems the default was 10](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/parallelizing-large-uploads-for-speed-and-reliability/)) seemed to do the trick. You can do it like so:

```
    TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(
            new AmazonS3Client(creds),
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT));
```

Note how I had to use a different constructor for `TransferManager`, but this did not require reworking anything (i.e., it was a drop-in replacement).